# Cannot install RMariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mysql, r, mariadb

I have tried many things and this is the error i get. It is similar when i try to install both RMariaDB and RMysql.

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RMariaDB.so DbConnection.o DbResult.o MariaBinding.o MariaResultImpl.o MariaResultPrep.o MariaResultSimple.o MariaRow.o MariaTypes.o MariaUtils.o RcppExports.o connection.o driver.o result.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lmariadb -lz -ldl -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'RMariaDB.so' failed

make: *** [RMariaDB.so] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMariaDB’
* removing ‘/home/panos/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RMariaDB’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMariaDB’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmppKrDU5/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The development files for the zlib library are missing (`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`); `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: Thank you that was helpful!. I googled the error and lz but could not find what lz was :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

the development files for the zlib library are missing.
Use

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

to install the missing files.